# Identify a story in which Superman marries a witch

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman, witches

I vaguely recall the following:

1. The comic was from the 1970's (could even be the 1960's) silver age type
2. It was a 'what if/untold story' type scenario
3. Superman falls in love with a girl get married
4. The girl reveals herself to be a ***witch*** by casting a spell and transforming herself
5. She dies during childbirth?
6. But a son is born to Superman
7. Superman is crying and holding his baby son wrapped in cloth

Can this DC comic be identified?

Comment: No. It can not.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Prove your conjecture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably "The Satanic Son of Superman", printed in *Action Comics* #410 in 1972. The portion you're remembering is actually a very small segment of the issue, serving as a backstory for the issue's villain (Superman's son's evil twin, and no I'm not making that up).

- **Superman falls in love and gets married**

  [image]

  **Relevant transcript:**

  > But as you suspend your monumental burden in space, Superman, your troubled mind wanders once again...through the misty realms of cherished memories to a happier time, years ago...
  >
  > When you and your young wife were discussing the future of your soon-to-be-born child...
  >
  > **Krysalla:** Darling, there's something about myself I must tell you...something I'm afraid might...affect our baby!

  Neither actually shown, but check
- **His wife turns out to be a witch**

  [image]

  **Relevant transcript:**

  > At first you wouldn't believe your eyes as she backed away from you...
  >
  > **Krysalla:** I...I am a witch. See?
- **She dies in childbirth, gives Superman a son, Superman is holding the baby crying**

  [image]

  **Relevant transcript:**

  > **Doctor:** I'm sorry, Superman! We tried everything possible to save her! But your newborn son is alive and healthy!
- **It was a what-if**

  [image]

  **Relevant transcript:**

  > The end of an imaginary story that hasn't happened yet -- but who can tell? Someday it might!

Comment: Spot on! Thanks!

Comment: Why is he wearing glasses in those two panels? Is that because if he ever takes them off Krysalla will find out she's married to Superman?

Comment: @user14111 Yep. One wonders how he managed to keep his secret *and* conceive a child, but that's probably a question best left unanswered

Comment: @user14111 Hey, some women dig glasses.